# PrestaShop Order-confirmation.tpl

Tags: smarty, prestashop, tracking

I got a prestashop with several modules installed.
Like MasterCard / PayPal and so on.

I got a Theme and in this Theme there is my order-confirmation.tpl file.
No i added a tracking code to this theme file.

But when i bought something in store - there is another order-confirmation.tpl shown.

Did i guess it right, that the paypal module is overwriting my theme file?

How / where can i put my code to work on all order-confirmation.tpl files?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The standard behavior is that every payment module redirect to default Prestashop order confirmation page. But, this not happen a lot. Just a few modules follow this standard procedure. Modules can have his own payment confirmation page, so you must look for it and add your code on it. Paypal has different versions with different confirmation pages each.

Good luck.

Comment: Oh my gosh :(
So i have to put my code in multiple tpls?
Is there a netter way - maybe in header.tpl?
Is there a function to check if the curremt page is my order-comfirmation page?

Comment: A validation does not work if payment module never redirect to Prestashop default order-confirmation page. If your tracking code is javascript (for Google Analitycs) for example...your are busted. If your code es PHP then you are saved and you can use hookOrderConfirmation. Good luck.